# Getting counts of column values in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a new dataframe from a preexisting one. It will be grouped on the `name` field, and then should have 3 separate count columns. The columns are the count of each unique value for the `type` field.

```
name     type
Bob      A
Phil     B
Phil     B
James    C
Bob      C
Phil     C
James    B
```

This should turn into

```
name     count_a     count_b     count_c
Bob      1           0           1
Phil     0           2           1
James    0           1           1
```

I have tried using a `pandas` groupby function, but cant figure out how to get the count of each rather than a count of the whole column.

Comment: This must be a duplicate: `pd.crosstab(df['name'], df['type'])`

Comment: Thanks. I probably would have found it if I realized I wanted a crosstab.